# Rcpp - Capture result of sregex_token_iterator to vector

Tags: c++, r, boost, rcpp

I'm an R user and am learning c++ to leverage in Rcpp.  Recently, I wrote an alternative to R's `strsplit` in Rcpp using `string.h` but it isn't regex based (afaik).  I've been reading about Boost and found sregex_token_iterator.

The website below has an example:

```
std::string input("This is his face");
sregex re = sregex::compile(" "); // find white space

// iterate over all non-white space in the input. Note the -1 below:
sregex_token_iterator begin( input.begin(), input.end(), re, -1 ), end;

// write all the words to std::cout
std::ostream_iterator< std::string > out_iter( std::cout, "\n" );
std::copy( begin, end, out_iter );
```

My `rcpp` function runs just fine:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive.hpp>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
StringVector testMe(std::string input,std::string uregex) {
  boost::xpressive::sregex re = boost::xpressive::sregex::compile(uregex); // find a date

  // iterate over the days, months and years in the input
  boost::xpressive::sregex_token_iterator begin( input.begin(), input.end(), re ,-1), end;

  // write all the words to std::cout
  std::ostream_iterator< std::string > out_iter( std::cout, "\n" );
  std::copy( begin, end, out_iter );
  return("Done");
}

/*** R
testMe("This is a funny sentence"," ")
*/
```

But all it does is print out the tokens.  I am very new to C++ but I understand the idea of making a vector in `rcpp` with `StringVector res(10);` (make a vector named res of length 10) which I can then index `res[1] = "blah"`.

My question is - how do I take the output of `boost::xpressive::sregex_token_iterator begin( input.begin(), input.end(), re ,-1), end;` and store it in a vector so I can return it?

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/xpressive/user_s_guide.html#boost_xpressive.user_s_guide.string_splitting_and_tokenization

---

**Final working Rcpp solution**

Including this because my need was Rcpp specific and I had to make some minor changes to the solution provided.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive.hpp>

typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVector; 
using boost::xpressive::sregex; 
using boost::xpressive::sregex_token_iterator;
using Rcpp::List;

void tokenWorker(/*in*/      const std::string& input, 
                 /*in*/      const sregex re,
                 /*inout*/   StringVector& v) 
{
  sregex_token_iterator begin( input.begin(), input.end(), re ,-1), end;

  // write all the words to v
  std::copy(begin, end, std::back_inserter(v));
}

//[[Rcpp::export]]
List tokenize(StringVector t, std::string tok = " "){
  List final_res(t.size());
  sregex re = sregex::compile(tok); 
  for(int z=0;z<t.size();z++){

    std::string x = "";

    for(int y=0;y<t[z].size();y++){
      x += t[z][y];
    }

    StringVector v;
    tokenWorker(x, re, v);
    final_res[z] = v;
  }
  return(final_res);
}

/*** R
tokenize("Please tokenize this sentence")
*/
```

Comment: You can just use a `back_inserter` on a `vector<string>` and call `Rcpp::wrap` on the result; e.g. `std::vector<std::string> result; std::copy(begin, end, std::back_inserter(result)); return Rcpp::wrap(result);`.

Comment: @Mark That `tokenize` function needs a rewrite. Concatenating strings you already have is pointless and you don't even need that `x` copy there; u make useless copies of t and v, and iterating with index `z` instead of a `const iterator` is at least dubious here because you use it just for dereferencing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is - how do I take the output of
>   boost::xpressive::sregex_token_iterator begin( input.begin(),
>   input.end(), re ,-1), end; and store it in a vector so I can return
>   it?

You're already halfway there.

The missing link is just [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive.hpp>

typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVector; 
using boost::xpressive::sregex; 
using boost::xpressive::sregex_token_iterator; 


void testMe(/*in*/      const std::string& input, 
            /*in*/      const std::string& uregex,
            /*inout*/   StringVector& v) 
{
    sregex re = sregex::compile(uregex); 

    sregex_token_iterator begin( input.begin(), input.end(), re ,-1), end;

    // write all the words to v
    std::copy(begin, end, std::back_inserter(v));
}

int main() 
{

    std::string input("This is his face");
    std::string blank(" ");
    StringVector v;
     // find white space
    testMe(input, blank, v);

    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), 
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "|"));

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
This|is|his|face|
```

I used legacy C++ because you used a regex lib from boost  instead of std `<regex>`; maybe you better consider C++14 right from the start when you learn c++ right now; C++14 would have shortened even this small snippet and made it more expressive.

Comment: Thanks for legacy c++ - `Rcpp` supports C++11 but I don't think it supports C++14.  So I'm looking into `std::back_inserter` and how to implement it.  The difference with what I'm trying to do is I need to return the `StringVector` because this is actually going to compile as a function be used in R.  I'm getting an indecipherable error message: "no viable overloaded '='" which points to a `_tree` file.

Comment: @Mark But you're sure it supports C++11? If so I'll be glad to update it; it'd be not abig deal, but a big improvement. .

Comment: @Mark: Not that I forget it - of course, you could return a `StringVector` instead of passing that as /*inout*/ param. But there is a little to be known about what will  actually happens with return values and if and why that would or would not be a (possibly expensive) copy in Legacy C++ . Search for "return value optimization" (RVO)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it supports C++11 though I barely understand what that means.

What I'm doing is creating a function that is compiled in C++ but through a library in R, is callable from R.  This is done to get performance enhancements on oft-reused or expensive functions.  I need to take in a string, parse it and return a StringVector.  It seems like you've given me the tools to do it (the error I mentioned goes away in certain cases and so I think I've about got it licked).

Comment: Rcpp supports whatever your compiler supports -- if you have g++ 5.2, say, you can turn C++14 on.  We do use C++11 quite a bit across CRAN packages. But yes, life will be easier once C++14 is more common as the missing regexp lib is a pain.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: In an ideal world or with standard-compilers compilers - yes. But if they support a certain older compiler (and lib) version, "supporting C++11" may require that they make up for possibly "not-then-implemented' C++11 or C++11 std lib features.

Comment: @decltype_auto All true but you *kinda miss the boat here* as we are talking *strictly* about R package builds where the compilers are given on some platforms and are fairly standardized on others.  This is not a plain C++(1x) thread, please keep that in mind.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: My crystal ball just doesn't tell me which c++-compiler *boats*  are in every *dock* where those R packages are to be built.

Comment: We do know. On Windows it can only be one.  On OS X it is mostly just one (via XCode).  That is the vast majority of users.  Over here in Linux it mostly current g++ and some clang++.  Anyway, not a criticism, I just don;t want you to waste your time here as you are talking past of the other participants _from whom this is an R / C++ question_ and not a generic C++ question.  Peace.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel `static_assert<mybook::is_constructive_criticism<decltype(msg)>::value, "">; peace();` compiled successfully. ;)

Answer (score 0):

And here's the C++11 version.

Aside from the benefits of using a standardized `<regex>`, the `<regex>`-using version compiles roughly twice as fast as the boost::xpressive version with gcc-4.9 and clang-3.5 (-g -O0 -std=c++11) on a QuadCore-Box running with Debian x86_64 Jessie.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// A minimal adaption layer atop boost::xpressive and c++11 std's <regex>   //
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// remove the comment sign from the #define if your compiler suite's        //
// <regex> implementation is not complete                                   //
//#define USE_REGEX_FALLBACK_33509467 1                                     //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#if defined(USE_REGEX_FALLBACK_33509467)
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive.hpp>
using regex = boost::xpressive::sregex; 
using sregex_iterator = boost::xpressive::sregex_token_iterator; 

auto compile = [] (const std::string& s) { 
    return boost::xpressive::sregex::compile(s);
}; 

auto make_sregex_iterator = [] (const std::string& s, const regex& re) {
    return sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), re ,-1);
};    

#else // #if !defined(USE_REGEX_FALLBACK_33509467)

#include <regex>
using regex = std::regex; 
using sregex_iterator = std::sregex_token_iterator; 

auto compile = [] (const std::string& s) { 
    return regex(s); 
}; 

auto make_sregex_iterator = [] (const std::string& s, const regex& re) {
    return std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), re, -1);
};    

#endif // #if defined(USE_REGEX_FALLBACK_33509467)
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVector; 


StringVector testMe(/*in*/const std::string& input, 
                    /*in*/const std::string& uregex)
{
    regex re = compile(uregex); 

    sregex_iterator begin = make_sregex_iterator(input, re), 
                    end;

    return StringVector(begin, end); // doesn't steal the strings
                                     // but try (and succeed) to move the vector
}

int main() {
    std::string input("This is his face");
    std::string blank(" ");

     // tokenize by white space
    StringVector v = testMe(input, blank);

    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), 
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "|"));

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I built this in Rcpp using the `<regex>` version (no boost) and that version of the function runs 12 times slower than the C++ solution.  Using boost gets them comparable but with no apparent speed benefit of C++11.

Comment: @Mark What do you mean with 'run' here - how long the compiler 'runs' or how long the function 'runs' on runtime? Please always state compiler version and options used along with statements about performance.

Comment: the numbers I referenced were for runtime execution being called from R post-compilation. I will try and figure out compiler version and options and post those.

Comment: @decltype_ato This is what I see in my compiler window

clang++ -std=c++11 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -DPLATFORM_PKGTYPE='"mac.binary.mavericks"'  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Users/mark/Documents/R Projects/rcpp workshop"    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2 -c second_attempt.cpp -o second_attempt.o

Comment: clang++ -std=c++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o sourceCpp_12.so second_attempt.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation

Comment: @Mark Thx; I'm just in the middle of sth; I'll get back 2 u tmrw.

Comment: @Mark: I still don't find your clang version in the output; use clang++ --version to find it out. But what I see yet is you don't use llvm's libc++ with clang. And there's just an .so linked, not an executable produced; how did you benchmark that? Btw I'm on a x86_64 cluster, not on a Mac.